# Avoid structural type with shapeless alternative

Tags: scala, shapeless

I want to find out if a particular class member is present in a given `case class` or not.

Following does give me that answer, failing at compile time which is right. (credit to Travis Brown)

```
scala>  def getIntId[A, R <: HList](a: A)(implicit
 |   gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
 |   sel: Selector.Aux[R, Witness.`'id`.T, Int]
 | ): Int = sel(gen.to(a))

 case class Foo(id: String)
 case class Bar(id: Int, name: String)

scala> getIntId(Bar(123, "bar"))
res3: Int = 123

scala> getIntId(Foo("12345"))
<console>:15: error: could not find implicit value for parameter sel:    shapeless.ops.record.Selector.Aux[R,Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("id")],Int]
          getIntId(Foo("12345"))
```

Now if I don't have a concrete type but `T` to pass into `getIntId` method, is there a way to get this to work with generic type `T` ?

**Update**
Say have a method called `findIdFromType` as described below which takes in type `T` (where `T` will always be a some `case class`). is it possible to make this work?

```
def findIdFromType[T](t:T) = {
  getIntId(t) //as expected doesn't compile
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you provide a use case as example?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella : I just updated question (Update section). let me know if I need to expand it even further? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`getIntId` requires two implicit parameters.

If you need to call it in the context of a local method, you need to prove that those parameters exist in such context.

In order to do so, you have to propagate the implicit evidence, like this

```
def findIdFromType[A, R <: HList](a: A)(implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
  sel: Selector.Aux[R, Witness.`'id`.T, Int]): Int = getIntId(a)
```

This of course is a completely useless example, but in case you want to perform other operations inside the wrapping method, this is the way to go: propagate the implicit evidence.