# generically populate a same field in all case classes which have a particular timestamp property

Tags: scala, slick

I have `case classes` which have `Option[java.sql.Timestamp]` field.

```
case class BooRow(id:Int, createdTs: Option[java.sql.Timestamp])

case class FooRow(id: Int, name:String, deptId:Int,createdTs:Option[java.sql.Timestamp])

case class BarRow(id:Int,name:String)
```

looking for a generic solution which is also compile time safe to observe incoming `case class` instance and if it finds `createdTs:Option[java.sql.Timestamp]` in it then populate it.

Originally thought started with looking at shapless and had posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077524/avoid-structural-type-with-shapeless-alternative). [Gabriele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846273/gabriele-petronella) 's answer is right in the context of that previous question but may be I wasn't clear enough in the question so not sure how to "catch" "implicit not found error for that shapeless solution" (for the `case class` which doesn't have `createdTs` field) somehow. Generic function should populate `createdTs` if found in a `case class` instance it was passed, if it doesn't find `createdTs` in an instance of a case class then do nothing.

I have tagged slick for this question because these are slick generated case classes (not the reason for tagging) but I assume this can be a common need (generically populating such timestamp columns) when dealing with slick/databases in general. To clarify, I am not looking for db based solutions (like triggers etc) but something at an application level also without using structural types.

**Edit:** Providing default value to `createdTs` in `case class` declaration is not a desired solution. That will stamp wrong timestamp when `case class` instance is created for an "update" query.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are expecting to arrive at instances of you case classes, one option might be to ensure the createdTs parameter is given a default value on creation:

```
case class BooRow(id:Int, createdTs: Option[java.sql.Timestamp] = Some(new java.sql.Timestamp((new java.util.Date).getTime)))
```

However, it isn't clear from your question if this can cover your particular use case.